Allocating Mutex in a Python Module Developed with C++
I want to create a C++ library that will support both C++-based and Python-based applications running on Windows 10. The C++ application is multi-threaded, so I protect critical sections in my library using mutexes. To provide a Python API for my library, I use Boost.Python (version 1.82.0) wrapper. However, the mutex lock causes the Python (3.9.11) crash.
While the Visual Studio 2022 debug build works, the release build causes the Python application to fail.
#include <boost/python.hpp>  
#include <mutex>  
#include <iostream>  

using namespace boost::python;  
  
class PyAPI {  
public:  
    PyAPI() { }  
    PyAPI(const PyAPI& ref) { }  
    virtual ~PyAPI() {}  
    void test_wrapper() {  
        std::cout << "before mMutex.lock();" << std::endl;  
        mMutex.lock();  
        std::cout << "after  mMutex.lock();" << std::endl;  
        mMutex.unlock();  
        std::cout << "after  mMutex.unlock();" << std::endl;  
    }  
    std::mutex mMutex;  
};  

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(PyMutex){  
    class_<PyAPI>("PyMutex", init<>())  // Exposing the default constructor  
        .def("test", &PyAPI::test_wrapper)  
    ;  
}  

Execution in Python:
Python 3.9.11 (tags/v3.9.11:2de452f, Mar 16 2022, 14:33:45) [MSC v.1929 64 bit  (AMD64)] on win32  

> import PyMutex  
> A = PyMutex.PyMutex()  
> A.test()  
> before mMutex.lock();  

Then I receive the Windows shell prompt.
I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

You can attach a C++ debugger to python to see where the dll crashes. i think there is a CRT clash somewhere. but i am not sure how to fix it if that's the case. how are you compiling this ?! Are you using proper versions (debug/release) of both boost python and the CRT ?

Hello Ahmed,
You were right. The CRT was not corresponding. I updated the C++ redistributable, and the problem disappeared. Thank you very much.

You could self-answer this question
